# MySQL query to get count of joined table B less than value of certain field in TABLE A

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with a MyQSL query.
I have two tables:

**quotes**

- id
- service_provider
- quote_amount
- required_repairs_id

**required_repairs**

- id
- repair_description
- quotes_required

table "required_repairs" is joined to table "quotes" via "required_repairs_id" field.

So when there's a new repair to be carried out, a new row is entered into the "required_repairs" table, with a description of the repair, and the minimum amount of quotes that are required from service providers. Then, as quotes are received from the service providers, they are entered in to the quotes table, with the corresponding repair id.

I need to create a MySQL query that will return the number of repairs that don't have sufficient quotes. i.e. number of repairs that have less quotes than are required for that repair.

I am really struggling with this query, if anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks  in advance...

Comment: first you do a count of quotes grouping by the required_repairs_id, then you can join that data to the required_repairs and compare to the quotes_required. have a go with this plan and post the attempt

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply amdixon.... Ok, will try that and let you know how it goes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(r.id)
from required_repairs r 
join 
(
   select required_repairs_id , count(id) as q_count
   from quotes 
   group by required_repairs_id 
) q on q.required_repairs_id = r.id
where q.q_count < r.quotes_required
```

Comment: Oh, thanks juergen, but I think I didn't explain the problem properly - sorry about that. The "quote_amount" field you refer to in you query is actually a currency field that stores what the service provider quoted for the repair job.
I need to display the number of repairs that have less quotes in the "quotes" table than the value in required_repairs.quotes_required